# Restrict a number of OTP credentials for a user on Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Starting from Keycloak 8.0.1 users can register multiple OTP devices:

[image: screen of user setup page on Keycloak admin ui]

Is there any way to restrict a number of OTP credentials (devices) for a user?
The behavior I want to achieve is to allow only one OTP device to be active for a user so users don't need to select a device from a dropdown on the login page (the behavior prior to the previous Keycloak versions).

Comment: Do you have any update on this? Is there any way to limit the number of the OTP devices?

Answer (score 1):

There is a related problem, when you do a OTP reset, a new OTP device is added. So no real reset I would say.
Being able to limit to only one OTP device in the list would in fact make it possible to reset the OTP as the new OTP would push previous OTP device out from the list.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make sense. You may somehow restrict user to have just one OTP device instance in the Keycloak. But you can't restrict user to have that single OTP instance on just single device. User can scan the same initial OTP QR code to many devices and then all these devices provide the same OTP code. (I use it as well, because single OTP device seems to be risky for me).

This kind of "OTP device replication" is not a problem especially for TOTP. HOTP may have a problem with that.

Comment: Hi, @jan-garaj, please, check the screenshot that I attached. I understand that user can scan the same code twice, but I want to restrict a number of credentials with type 'otp' on Keycloak.